# ng-grid: how show checkbox for true/false value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid

In angularjs script i have the "ng-grid" module and, in one column, i want show the checkbox control instead of the true/false string returned from json data.
The checkbox must be checked if the json variable is true and unchecked if false.

I think i must use the template but i don't know how.

How can i show the checkboxes? There are some examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this: **updated with change handler**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myData = [{
        name: "Moroni",
        age: 50,
        dude: true
      }, {
        name: "Tiancum",
        age: 43,
        dude: true
      }, {
        name: "Jacob",
        age: 27,
        dude: false
      }, {
        name: "Nephi",
        age: 29,
        dude: true
      }, {
        name: "Enos",
        age: 34,
        dude: false
      }];
      $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{
          field: 'name',
          displayName: 'Name'
        }, {
          field: 'age',
          displayName: 'Age'
        }, {
          field: 'dude',
          displayName: 'Dude',
          cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.dude" ng-click="toggle(row.entity.name,row.entity.dude)">'
        }]
      };

      $scope.toggle = function(name, value) {
        //do something usefull here, you have the name and the new value of dude. Write it to a db or else. 
        alert(name + ':' + value);
      }
    });
```

You now can add an change handler or just set the input to disable/readonly if you just want to display the value.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXdkrQFO8QU5pbTwQEC6?p=preview)

[Plunker with change handler](http://plnkr.co/edit/9eRg9Yjl2ooeSuWMJ8x2?p=preview)

(I'm so sorry for Jacob and Enos!)

Comment: It works! Thanks. Now i want handle the ngGridEventEndCellEdit event and i succesfull handle it when i edit the fields excepts for the checkbox. How can i get the checkbox to emit that event?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a cellTemplate when you define you ng-grid definition of fields. See "[String-based Cell Templates](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)" section in the documentation for example

```
 {field:'age', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{green: row.getProperty(col.field) > 30}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}]
        };
```

It uses `div`, you can use `input`.